# What is a .PE file in the .NET framework?

Tags: c#

I want to know what is .PE file in .net projects, is it project specic and generated for each project once we compile it.
Also .PE file keeps metadata+manifest info for a assemble.
Also i am confuse on is there for each class in project CLR generates a .dll.

Comment: PE = portable executable, which is massively googlible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PE file you are talking about is the "Portable Executable" format. Almost every EXE and DLL on the Windows platform is formatted in PE format. To answer your question, it's a general format and every assembly generated after compilation of your project will be a PE file. You will have a PE file for every .NET project you compile.
You can read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable

And no, not every class in a project results in a new DLL. Every project in a solution will result in a new DLL or Executable.

Comment: This is important to me..Every project in a solution will result in a new DLL or Executable.

Comment: But .PE file always generated or it comes after setup and deployment?

Comment: PE files are generated after a project is compiled. When using Visual Studio it will end up in the bin folder as a .EXE or .DLL.

Answer (score 5):

It is not a file but [the first section of any executeable file that the OS loads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable).

All windows executeables contain a PE header, in .NET executeables the header invokes the CLR virtual machine that .NET runs under (or gives you the error message saying you do not have .NET installed if you are targeting a version of .NET that is missing on the machine).

Answer (score 3):

Metadata is stored in one section of a .NET Framework **portable executable (PE)** file.
When a program is compiled for the common language runtime, 
it is converted to a PE file that consists of following three parts.

> PE header  : The index of the PE file's main sections and the address
>   of the entry point. MSIL instructions :The Microsoft intermediate
>   language instructions (MSIL) that make up your code Metadata :
>   Metadata tables and heaps.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dkk3ek4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: So manifest is different from PE file.